# Euler method to model terminal velocity NOT converging?

Tags: python-3.x

As per the title I am trying to model a parachutist's decent in Python 3.
I need to use an Euler method for a kinematic body. The graph plotting speed shows no signs of tending to a terminal velocity, so I'm clearly doing something very wrong!
[image]

For fault finding I have printed the list of t and speed values to the screen. Here is the code, for a function that returns lists of the values, then plots them.

```
def Euler_n2l(y_ini,v_yini):

    delta_t=float(input("Type time interval size (in s): "))
    t_n=0
    t_list=[0]
    y_list=[]
    v_list=[v_yini]

    #Calculating k from the specified parameters for: drag      coefficient, cross-sectional area and air density.
    k=(userC*rho0*ca)/2

    while (y_ini>0):                #Ending the simulation when the ground is reached
                t_n += delta_t
                v_yini -= delta_t*(9.81+((k/m)*(v_yini)**2))
                y_ini += delta_t*v_yini
                t_list.append(t_n)
                y_list.append(y_ini)
                v_list.append(v_yini)

                if y_ini < 0:
                    del t_list[-2:]
                    del y_list[-1]
                    del v_list[-2:]


     return t_list,y_list,v_list 

ca=0.96         #Approximation for an average human cross sectional area=1.6*0.6 m^2
userC=float(input("Type a value for the drag coefficient, C_d. Sensible values are from ~1.0 - 1.3: "))
rho0=1.2    #Value given the instruction for ambient temperature and pressure
m=80    #approx weight of a man in Kg

output=Euler_n2l(39000,0)
t_list,y_list,v_list=output


plt.plot(t_list,v_list)
plt.xlabel("$Time (s)$", size=12)
plt.ylabel("$Speed (m/s)$", size=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Where is `m` defined, and to be what?  What did you enter for `delta_t` to produce the displayed graph?  What were you expecting the graph to look like?

Comment: Graph should tend to a terminal vecloty of ~300 m/s.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: The code appears to calculate drag based on the initial velocity, instead of the current velocity.